# PHP SELECT loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a School database with two courses, each course has 12 possible subject fields (`co_subj...`) that can contain the subject ID or NULL, in this case course ID 1 has 3 subjects, and course 2 has only 1:

[image: Courses]

I need PHP to create a `<div>` for each subject found on a course, and don't create nothing in any NULL case. Querys:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM course_conf JOIN course_type ON ct_id=co_fk_ct_id ORDER BY co_name");
```

And then a while makes PHP check every course's field:

```
while($registroBbdd = mysql_fetch_array($select))
                {
                    $class="";
                    $courseId=$registroBbdd['co_id'];
                    $courseName=$registroBbdd['co_name'];
                    $courseType=$registroBbdd['ct_name'];
```

The doubt comes right now, trying to solve the most efficient way the `<div>` creating I mentioned before. The only way I find to solve this is creating a conditional "IF" structure printing the  if a value is found, and nothing if NULL is found, like this:

```
if($registroBbdd['co_subj1'] != NULL){
     echo "<div>'.$registroBbdd['co_subj1'].'</div>}
else if ($registroBbdd['co_subj2'] != NULL){
     echo "<div>'.$registroBbdd['co_subj2'].'</div>}
.............}
```

Is there any looping way to make this? In order to avoid the whole "if" structure creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the SQL statement do the work. For example:

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN co_subj1 IS NOT NULL THEN co_subj1 ELSE co_subj2 END) AS subject 
FROM course_conf JOIN course_type ON ct_id=co_fk_ct_id ORDER BY co_name
WHERE co_subj1 IS NOT NULL OR co_subj2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: or, just **`IFNULL(co_subj1,co_subj2) AS subject`**

Comment: Thank you for your help, finally soved with a loop.

Comment: IFNULL is nice and concise. I lose track if which SQL versions and dialects support what, but that one's ubuquitous, right? @Biomehanika, I think it's faster, more maintainable, with less code to let the SQL statement prepare the results the way you want. Maybe give it a try!

Comment: I have just solved this with a loop but I feel you are right. This makes a lighter proccess and it seems truly easyer and simplyer than looping everything. I'm gonna change it to a pre-selected non-nul fields :) But once just not-null fields are selected, how do I identify them and print them separately?

Comment: the purpose of the CASE statement (or the IFNULL in @spencer's improved version) is to give you a new field in your query called "subject" which contains either co_subj1 or co_subj2 as necessary. So in your loop, don't use an if-else, always do this:
echo "<div>'.$registroBbdd['subject'].'</div>

Comment: you're welcome. Much simpler looking code now, isn't it? Not that it's always OK to push complexity down into the SQL, but often the SQL engine is way more optimized than a PHP loop through the results would be.

Comment: But... it only works with 2 exxpressions, and I have 12 fields to check isnt it? :(

Comment: There are in total 12 possible subjects so ISNULL as far as I know can not be used for this..

Comment: IFNULL() works with 2 arguments, but COALESCE() works with as many as you like

Answer (score 2):

What about trying a via a loop with isset($registroBbdd['co_subj'+$i])